# Изумление "чему-то" или "чем-то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как будет правильно: "изумление собственному существованию" или "изумление собственным существованием"?

Answer (score 1):

Глаголы **изумиться, изумляться** требуют дательного падежа, в то время как причастие **изумлённый (изумлён)** — творительного. Это зафиксировано в справочнике Д.Э. Розенталя. Я думаю, что в связи с этим слово **изумление** допускает оба варианта, в частности, это можно наблюдать и в художественной литературе. Пример с творительным падежом можно найти во втором томе "Русской грамматики": **изумление смелостью**.

Лингвисты отмечают, что правила управления слов, связанных с эмоциями (удивляться, изумляться, восхищаться, поражаться и т.п.), активно эволюционируют в русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос интересен тем, что в словарях затруднительно найти рекомендацию по управлению от существительного. Предлагаемые вами варианты управления характерны для глагола **изумляться** (чему) и причастия **изумлённый/изумлён** (чем). Они приводятся, в частности, Розенталем в справочнике по управлению в русском языке. Эти формы *производны* от существительного **изумление**, обозначающего эмоциональное *состояние* (сильное удивление), но не действие. Поэтому нет достаточных оснований позаимствовать управление непосредственно от глагольных форм. То же можно сказать и о слове **впечатление** (в условном смысле изумление - частный случай впечатления), которое большую часть истории своего существования не имело производных глаголов "впечатлять" и "впечатляться" (чем) и по управлению сохранило только вариант "впечаление от (чего/кого)", отличающийся от глагольного. В нашем случае аналогичное управление, указывающее на причину, столь же безупречно: "**изумление от чего**".

> изумление **от** (факта) собственного существования

В корпусе находится только "изумление **от того**" (нет **тому** или **тем**):

> ... вспомнилось мне восклицание одной генеральши, пришедшей в изумление **от того**, что знакомая ей крестьянская девушка отказалась от богатого
>   жениха из-за любви к какому-то бедному.  [Н. А. Морозов. Повести моей
>   жизни/ Во имя братства (1912)]

Однако вопрос о допустимости управления **чему/чем** (по аналогии с глагольным) остаётся, поскольку (в отличие от "впечатления") глагольные формы сосуществовали с существительным **изумление** практически всегда. Более того, в печатных изданиях после слова изумление встречается не только форма управления **от чего**, но и **чем** и **чему**.

> Не могу не заметить при этом случае, что многие **изъявляли изумление**
>   **тому**, что я так желаю известий о России... (Гоголь, О сословиях в
>   государстве)

(изумление тем):

> Xудожник должен заставить зрителя обратить внимание на конкретный факт
>   жизни, любоваться им, **вызвать** в его душе восхищение и **изумление
>   тем**, что он не увидел раньше такую красоту. (Т. МАхмудов, Эстетика
>   идуховные ценности)

**Выводы.** На мой взгляд, из факта сосуществования всех трёх вариантов **не** следует их полная взаимозаменяемость (в первом примере нельзя сказать "пришёл в изумление тем-то). Дело в том, что само существительное обозначает эмоцию (условно *бессодержательное* состояние), причина и содержание которой находятся во внешнем контексте. При статичном описании "изумления" ("он находится в состоянии изумления") всегда можно указать на причину предложным выражением **от (того)**. В некоторых же сочетаниях этого слова с глаголом возникает  возможность для глагольных форм управления (проявить изумление ~= **изумиться** *тому*; вызвать у него изумление ~= сделать его **изумлённым** *тем*). По этой причине окончательно определиться с выбором, проставленным в вопросе, можно только имея достаточный контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем словарь и читаем:

> ИЗУМИТЬСЯ, -млюсь, -мишься; св. (чему). Прийти в изумление; удивиться. Представляю, как он изумится, получив твоё письмо. <Изумляться, -яюсь, -яешься; нсв. Не перестаю и. твоим приключениям.

Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова.